# How to check if range contains certain value

Tags: excel, if-statement

I have a sheet that is tracking "wins" for a SKU. I want to create a pivot to see how many wins a supplier.

A supplier can have many SKUs associated to it, so even one SKU win would be considered a win for the supplier.

If a supplier has 4 SKUs associated to it and one has a win, but the other 3 don’t, I still want to consider that Supplier has having a win.

Any thoughts on how I can get that formula into column D?

```
sku        Supplier   Win     Does Supplier have any win

abc1234    ABC        No      Yes

abc1235    ABC        Yes     Yes

abc1236    ABC        No      Yes

abc1237    ABC        No      Yes

bb1234     BBB        No      No

bbb1235    BBB        No      No
```

Comment: A sheet, as in Excel?

Comment: learn, how to post a good question.

Answer (score 1):

If `sku` is in A1, please try in D2:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(B:B,B2,C:C,"Yes")>0,"Yes","No")
```

copied down to suit.

Answer (score 0):

For a pivot table, drag Supplier into the row panel, Win under supplier and Win into totals. Now you can see a count of Wins per value.
[image]